# How to determine a number wether it's prime or not using while

Tags: c++

i am a first semester university student. I am trying to make a program that determine wether the number is prime or not (Ex : if i input 2, there will be an output saying it's a prime number). To make this program, is it possible if i use while loop?

Here's a thing i have tried :

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,b;
    
    cout<<"Number : ";
    cin>>a;
    b = 2;
    
    
    while(a%b==0){
        b=b+1;
    }
    cout<<"This number : "<<a<<" is a prime number";
}
```

But every number i input, it says it's a prime number

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: How would you do it by hand / on paper? What have you tried?  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use a `while` loop, but you need to think some more about how long the loop will last for and what should happen inside it. And it also looks like you need to review what the definition of a prime number is (it isn't "a number is prime if there is at least one number that doesn't divide it").

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some remarks/directions:

- Your program currently has only one outcome.  So, without looking at your logic, it will either run forever or will say it's prime.
- Your brute-force method can and should stop at square-root of `a`.
- `a % b` is the remainder of `a` divided by `b`.  The remainder becomes 0 when `a` is a multiple of `b` (i.e. when it's **not** prime).

Good luck; I'm sure you can get it right.

(As suggested in the comments, there are much more efficient algorithms, but using a loop is a nice exercise.)